# Is this undefined behaviour or a bug with struct init?

Tags: c++, struct, language-lawyer, object-lifetime, list-initialization

Please consider this bit of code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    struct A 
    { 
        int x; 
        int y; 
        int z; 

        int foo()
        {
            std::cout << "enter foo: " << this->x << "," << this->y << "," << this->z << std::endl;
            return 5;
        }       

        int moo() 
        { 
            std::cout << "enter moo: " << this->x << "," << this->y << "," << this->z << std::endl;
            this->x = 1;
            this->z = 10;
            return 2; 
        }
    };

    A b { b.foo(), b.z = b.moo(), 3};

    std::cout << "final: " << b.x << "," << b.y << "," << b.z << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The result in my VS2017 (x64 release):

```
enter foo: 0,0,0
enter moo: 5,0,0
final: 1,2,3
```

The result from ideone.com (gcc 6.3) https://ideone.com/OGqvjW):

```
enter foo: 0,0,3
enter moo: 5,0,3
final: 1,2,2
```

One compiler sets `z` member to 3 immediately, before everything, then overwrites it when methods and assignments are called, another does it at the very end, after everything.

**Q. What would be the explanation to such behaviour?**

Thank you.

Comment: you have used object elements before construction. Why do you expect a result different from what you got?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, this is undefined behavior:

```
int foo()
{
    std::cout << "enter foo: " << this->x << "," << this->y << "," << this->z << std::endl;
    //                            ~~~~~~~           ~~~~~~~           ~~~~~~~
}
```

At the point that `foo()` is invoked, `x`, `y`, and `z` have not been initialized yet. From [[dcl.init]/12](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#12):

> If no initializer is specified for an object, the object is default-initialized. When storage for an object with automatic or dynamic storage duration is obtained, the object has an *indeterminate value*, and if no initialization is performed for the object, that object retains an indeterminate value until that value is replaced ([expr.ass]). [...] If an indeterminate value is produced by an evaluation, the behavior is undefined except in the following cases: [...]

None of the remaining cases apply. So printing `x`, `y`, and `z` there is undefined behavior. No different from just:

```
int x;
std::cout << x; // ub
```

---

My previous answer said yes, but for lifetime reasons. It had suggested that the initialization in `A b{ b.foo(), b.z = b.moo(), 3};` is non-vacuous and hence any access of any of the members of `b` before the end of initialization is UB. However, xskxzr has since indicated to me that in order for initialization to be non-vacuous, you [must have constructors invoked](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.life#1.sentence-2), and `int` does not have constructors. This makes the initialization of `b` vacuous. Which seems conceptually odd to me, but the wording in this regard is clear.

Comment: I suppose this wouldn't be any different for `A b = { b.foo(), b.z = b.moo(), 3};`?

Comment: I'm a bit rusty in C++, especially after few recent changes, but I find it highly amusing that identifier 'b' is usable/available in the same "line" it is defined `A b { b.foo() }`. Certainly, `b.foo(); A b;` is not allowed. Static-access like `A b { A::foo() }` is of course allowed, but why would instance-access `A b { b.foo() }` ever be allowed before end of declaration/initialization? Are there any non-UB uses of such code construct? Yet another case like placement-new and taking address of uninitialized things or something like that?

Comment: @KillzoneKid No, that means the same thing in this context.

Comment: @Barry Thank you for explaining, much appreciated!

Comment: @quetzalcoatl I think it just makes the rules simpler to not carve out exceptions. There may be a better explanation, but I don't know.

Comment: The construction is not non-vacuous because it does not invoke a constructor. Anyway, [class.base.init/16](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/class.base.init#16) allows member functions to be called for an object under construction. I think the problem in the code is outputting indeterminate values.

Comment: @xskxzr It's not non-vacuous construction, it's non-vacuous *initialization*. That section doesn't apply because we're not in a constructor.

Comment: Sorry for my careless words... What I want to say is that it's **not** non-vacuous initialization because "an object is said to have non-vacuous initialization if ... and **it or one of its subobjects is initialized by a constructor** ...". The words in [class.base.init]/16 does not say the call must be in a constructor (though the example does).

Comment: @xskxzr Well, yes. The [full phrase](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.life#1.sentence-2) is "constructor other than a trivial default constructor." Our subobjects are all initialized by a constructor other than a trivial default constructor - they're all copied, which is non-vacuous (as the subsequent note emphasizes). Put in other words, this initialization *does stuff*, therefore it's non-vacuous. `int a;` doesn't do stuff, so it's vacuous.

Comment: Copying a scalar type is not non-vacuous. Otherwise, how do you interpret that initialization like `unsigned char x = x;` is [well-defined](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/basic.scope.pdecl#1)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162235/discussion-between-xskxzr-and-barry).

Comment: I have searched "non-vacuous initialization", and find in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43888263/5376789) the poster points out that a pointer has vacuous initialization though it indeed has an initializer. Anyway, I think since the standards gives an explicit definition for the term "non-vacuous initialization", we should follow this definition instead of interpreting it in plain English. BTW, we'd better move this discussion to chat...

Comment: Your std quotes are patently false

Comment: @curiousguy Um, what? The quotes are real quotes.

Comment: @Barry The words are real, the meaning is patently false, like many things in the std. The words of the std, for many iterations, could be taken to mean unions were not usable in any way. Not to be taken seriously